# Wrapper class error

Tags: vb.net

I added a dll to my project.  There was some error in the wrapper class so I removed that from my project.  Now the trouble is whenever I build my solution, following error appears:

"Error   1   Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "AxUrdu_Unicode_TextBox". Compiler errors occurred when generating a Windows Forms wrapper for ActiveX control 'AxUrdu_Unicode_TextBox'. Source code saved in 'obj\Debug\AxInterop.Urdu_Unicode_TextBox.cs'.
c:\Users\Kh. Furqn\AppData\Local\Temp\mhveuttt.0.cs(30,38) : error CS0407: 'object AxUrdu_Unicode_TextBox.AxctlUrduText.About()' has the wrong return type
    D:.Net Programs\School Manager\School Manager\School Manager\AxUrdu_Unicode_TextBox    School Manager
"

I have done Clean Solution several times but error does not go away.  Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am presumming that you have a WinForms App, try looking in your Designer.vb file to check if there are any reference's to the Dll that gave you a problem.

Comment: Try going into your project property pages and look at the references to make sure it is still not being referenced